# Не переходит с одной страницы jsp на другую

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть контроллер:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView start() {
        return new ModelAndView("start", "user", new User());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/input", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView input(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        return new ModelAndView("input", "userName", user);
    }
}
```

start.jsp - страница которая открывается вначале:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>start</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>TEST</h1>

<form:form method="post" commandName="user" action="input">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Сначала открывается localhost:8080/webapp и вводится name. User это просто модель в которой 1 поле String name. Далее по нажатию кнопки LOGIN переходит на localhost:8080/input а должно на localhost:8080/webapp/input

Comment: в action напишите "/input"

Comment: @Виктор не работает, попробовал из соображений написать webapp/input заработало. Но я же не могу так оставить, в реальном проекте я же не знаю изначально название домена.

Comment: @j6wj1997 action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/input" должно сработать

Comment: @fromSPb да это помогло, напишите ответ на вопрос более развернутый почему это так, если вам известно.

Comment: @j6wj1997 сейчас неудобно писать развёрнутый ответ. Если вкратце, то "contextPath" и даёт как раз то, что вы хотите - независимость от названия приложения. Назовёте по-другому вместо "webapps" - зарезолвится с другим именем. Если задеплоите варник с именем ROOT, будет подставляться "/". https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath--